# How do I generate text with a button/clickable area?

Tags: javascript, html, button, text

I was trying to create clickable text (and eventually) a self created buttons that would generate text in a defined area. When I click "This will generate the text" it will flash there for not even a second and disappear.

Note: In the end there will be multiple buttons to generate text in the same area, so I need to have the text get replaced.

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
a:hover{
    color: #0FC;
}
#button {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left
}
#text{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 495px;
    width: 395px;
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
}
```

Javascript

```
   <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="My First JavaScript Function";
    }
   </script>
   </head>
```

HTML

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="button">   
<p><a href="">
<span onclick="myFunction()">This will generate the text</span>
</a></p>
   </div> 
   <div id="text"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Why don't you try this with jquery? It takes more easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `<a>` tag that doesn't link to anything. When you click it, it will try to follow through that 'empty' link. You can fix it either with simply putting `<a href="#">`... or by removing the `<a>` all together and styling the `<p>` with css to make it look clickable like you want it.

Method 1: http://jsfiddle.net/eshellborn/VXD4K/

Method 2: http://jsfiddle.net/eshellborn/VXD4K/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since your `<a>` tag is empty and when you click it it relocates the page.Instead Try this:

```
<p><a href="#"><span onclick="myFunction()">This will generate the text</span>
</a></p>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hSe/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make text appear, you can do it with a `<div>` tag like this:

```
<div id="textgen" style="display: none">Your Text Here</div>
<button id="button" onclick="genText()">Your button text</button>
<script>
 function genText() {
  document.getElementById("textgen").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

And optionally, you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2NsRD/) JSFiddle HTML code to make it much more complicated and fun to use.